# Issue Implementing Admob Ads Dependency

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

When i try to add admob add dependency which is

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

```
https://imgur.com/XodA9vJ
```

error details:

> > All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version >specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions >28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector->drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... >(Ctrl+F1) 
> >     Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and >libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such >incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries >that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your >targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

tried to change lower appcombat version

```
//code
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "highproteinfoodsofalltimes.com.highproteinfoods"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this 3 lines to your dependency build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```